# Could not able to update table in SQLite database :android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I did updating in SQLite database table in other project it works fine, in this case also everything is seems to be fine but showing an error. Here is code of updating table:

```
public void updateNamePhone(ArrayList<String> seekerList, ArrayList<String> nameList, ArrayList<String> phoneList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
    for(int i=0;i<seekerList.size();i++){
    ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
    editCon.put(KEY_NAME, nameList.get(i));
    editCon.put(KEY_PHONE, phoneList.get(i));               
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, KEY_REGID+"="+seekerList.get(i), null);     
    }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Three array lists are:

```
seekerList:[Chandigarh, Mohali, Panchkula, Ambala]
nameList:[Vikram, Ashish, Rohit, Sunny]
phonelist:[989,98763,564838,33224]
```

All table columns are in Text type while created.

Here is error caught:

```
05-01 09:08:11.234: E/Database(25886): updateWithOnConflict |Error updating table = seekersList
05-01 09:08:11.234: I/System.out(25886): no such column: Chandigarh: , while compiling: UPDATE seekersList SET person_phone=?, person_name=? WHERE person_regid=Chandigarh
```

Comment: provide person_regid value in single quote as it is of type text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason for your error:

> no such column: Chandigarh: , while compiling: UPDATE seekersList SET
>   person_phone=?, person_name=? WHERE person_regid=Chandigarh

You need to put quotes around any searched strings like this:

> UPDATE seekersList SET person_phone=?, person_name=? WHERE person_regid='Chandigarh'

so in your code edit like:

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, KEY_REGID+"='"+seekerList.get(i)+"'", null);
```

Comment: Thanks bro for saving my time and giving quick response, its working too.thanx alot.

Answer (score 0):

Change your update to

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, KEY_REGID+"=?",   
                             new String[]{seekerList.get(i)});
```

Comment: Thank you brother. Its working. Its embarrassing mistake which i could not able to find.Sorry for inconvenience. Thanx alot